# What’s this brown growth on my yucca?

Tags: growth, yucca

There’s a brown growth at the base of one of the leaves of my Yucca plant. Should I remove it? What is it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an [adventitious root](https://academic.oup.com/plphys/article/170/2/603/6114063?login=false).  Yucca's will grow roots out of the stem which can act to brace the main plant which can get quite heavy.

No action is necessary on your part.